# PHP get variable from json results

Tags: php, json

Using PHP I have a json result of

```
{"text_block":[{"text":"XYZ","left":0,"top":0,"width":10,"height":12}]}
```

I can get this printed by the below code:

```
$json= file_get_contents('https://api.url');
$result = json_decode($json, true); //this returns an array
$result = json_decode($json);
$data = get_object_vars(json_decode($json));
$data = array_slice( $data, 0, 10 ); // now you can array functions
echo json_encode( $data );
```

but need to put the text "XYZ" into a variable for further use in PHP script. How can I do this, I've check various sources but don't seem to be getting anywhere! Thanks

Comment: Why are you `json_decode`ing three times?  Is that testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = json_decode($data,true);
$my_text = $res['text_block'][0]['text'];
```

now you can use my_text as a variable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value "XYZ" would be in

```
$data["text_block"][0]["text"]
```

Temporarily change the last line to var_dump($data) so you can get familiar with the php array structure.

Comment: array(1) { ["text_block"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (5) { ["text"]=> string(7) "XYZ" ["left"]=> int(0) ["top"]=> int(0) ["width"]=> int(10) ["height"]=> int(128) } } }

Comment: That looks right, you have an an object inside two nested arrays.  Each element of each object or array has a key, the first key we want is "text_block", second is 0, third is "text".  Do you see how that correlates to the answer?